# Cでのbase64デコードについて

Tags: c, decode, base64

Wikibooksに載っているCでbase64のデコード(下記のコード)についてわからないことがあります

[Algorithm Implementation/Miscellaneous/Base64 - Wikibooks, open books for an open world](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Miscellaneous/Base64#C_2)

char d[]のデータは何を表しているのでしょうか?
なぜ、66(INVALID)が多いのでしょうか?

また、6bitの値を24bitにまとめる際に`buf = buf << 6 | c;`となっていますが、`c`との論理和をとることにはどのような意味があるのでしょうか?

```
#define WHITESPACE 64
#define EQUALS     65
#define INVALID    66

static const unsigned char d[] = {
    66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,64,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,
    66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,62,66,66,66,63,52,53,
    54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,66,66,66,65,66,66,66, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
    10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,66,66,66,66,66,66,26,27,28,
    29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,66,66,
    66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,
    66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,
    66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,
    66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,
    66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,
    66,66,66,66,66,66
};

int base64decode (char *in, size_t inLen, unsigned char *out, size_t *outLen) { 
    char *end = in + inLen;
    char iter = 0;
    uint32_t buf = 0;
    size_t len = 0;

    while (in < end) {
        unsigned char c = d[*in++];

        switch (c) {
        case WHITESPACE: continue;   /* skip whitespace */
        case INVALID:    return 1;   /* invalid input, return error */
        case EQUALS:                 /* pad character, end of data */
            in = end;
            continue;
        default:
            buf = buf << 6 | c;
            iter++; // increment the number of iteration
            /* If the buffer is full, split it into bytes */
            if (iter == 4) {
                if ((len += 3) > *outLen) return 1; /* buffer overflow */
                *(out++) = (buf >> 16) & 255;
                *(out++) = (buf >> 8) & 255;
                *(out++) = buf & 255;
                buf = 0; iter = 0;

            }   
        }
    }

    if (iter == 3) {
        if ((len += 2) > *outLen) return 1; /* buffer overflow */
        *(out++) = (buf >> 10) & 255;
        *(out++) = (buf >> 2) & 255;
    }
    else if (iter == 2) {
        if (++len > *outLen) return 1; /* buffer overflow */
        *(out++) = (buf >> 4) & 255;
    }

    *outLen = len; /* modify to reflect the actual output size */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ちなみに`unsigned char c = d[*in++]`の添え字の部分がバグっていますね。char型は環境によっては符号付きの場合がありますので、`unsigned char`にキャストする必要があります。

Answer (score 6):

Base64とASCIIコードに関する基本的な知識が必要です。

Base64と言うのは6bitの値`000000`(=0)...`111111`(=63)の64通りのビットパターンを以下の規則によって、ASCII文字のうちの64個を使用して表します。

```
A (0x41=65)  -> 000000(=0)
B (0x42=66)  -> 000001(=1)
:
Z (0x5A=90)  -> 011001(=25)
a (0x61=97)  -> 011010(=26)
b (0x62=98)  -> 011011(=27)
:
z (0x7A=122) -> 110011(=51)
0 (0x30=48)  -> 110100(=52)
1 (0x31=49)  -> 110101(=53)
:
9 (0x39=57)  -> 111101(=61)
+ (0x2B=43)  -> 111110(=62)
/ (0x2F=47)  -> 111111(=63)
```

例えばASCII文字の`B`は、Base64では`000001`(=1)を表すので、`B`の文字コード(0x42=66)をインデックスとして`d[66]`をアクセスすると、値が`1`になるようにできています。0...63の値を表す文字をコメントとして付け加えてやると、`d[]`はこんな風に書けます。

```
static const unsigned char d[] = {
//                                \n
    66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,64,66,66,66,66,66,
//
    66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,
//                                    +           /
    66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,62,66,66,66,63,
//   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9           =
    52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,66,66,66,65,66,66,
//      A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O
    66, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,14,
//   P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z
    15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,66,66,66,66,66,
//      a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o
    66,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,
//   p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z
    41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,66,66,66,66,66,
    66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,
    66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,
    66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,
    66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,
    66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,
    66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,
    66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,
    66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66
};
```

***char d[]のデータは何を表しているのでしょうか?***

つまり文字コードをインデックスとして`d[]`の値を求めると、Base64でその文字の表す値が求められるわけです。

***なぜ、66(INVALID)が多いのでしょうか?***

1バイトで表される文字コードのうち、Base64で意味を持つのは上記の64文字の他はごくわずか(`=`など)しかありませんので、必然的に他の文字コードを表す位置は無効(INVALID)となります。

***cとの論理和をとることにはどのような意味があるのでしょうか?***

Base64では、上記のように1文字が6ビット、つまり4文字で24ビットを表します。`ABCD`と言う4文字を24ビットのデータに直す時に`ABC`まで読んだ後では

```
buf=     00000000000000000000000001000010
                       <--A-><--B-><--C->
```

となっているので、

```
buf<<6 = 00000000000000000001000010000000
                 <--A-><--B-><--C->
  c =                            00000011 <- cは`D`から変換
                                   <--D->
```

この2つの論理和をとることにより、計算後の`buf`の値が:

```
buf(新)= 00000000000000000001000010000011
                 <--A-><--B-><--C-><--D->
```

のように、`A`, `B`, `C` そして `D`の4文字の表す6ビットの値をつなげた24ビットの値にできるわけです。

Answer (score 2):

`d`はASCIIコードと64進数の対応を表しています。
ですので配列の要素数は1バイト分の`256`で、インデックスが`A`～`Z`、`a`～`z`、`0`-`9`、`+`、`/`に対応する要素に`0`～`63`が割り振られています。